# command to put hyphen in the second column if the space is given between a word

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

Suppose you have a file called `test.txt` with data like:

```
you wel come
how nice
what do ing
```

How can I add a hyphen in the second column if the space is given between a word?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "if the space is given between a word"? Please [edit] your question and show us your desired output. Should a hyphen be added each time there are three "words" on a line?

Comment: if my mind-reading is working today, I'm guessing you want to hyphenate words were split by spaces instead of hyphens?

Comment: What determines whether or not to hyphenate in a line such as `with in tent`?

Comment: Ooh, good one!  Here, let me try: `kitchen counter intuitive`.  Or `red car nation`.

Answer (score 4):

To replace the second space character of each line with a `-`:

```
$ sed 's/ /-/2' test.txt
you wel-come
how nice
what do-ing
```

To replace every space character of each line except the first, with GNU `sed`:

```
sed 's/ /-/2g'
```

With every sed:

```
sed -e :1 -e 's/ /-/2;t1'
```

To replace every other space with a `-` on each line:

```
sed 's/\( [^ ]*\) /\1-/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would the `read` command with 2 variable names. That will slurp the first word into the first variable and all the other words into the 2nd variable. Then I can use bash parameter substitution to replace spaces with hyphens.

```
while read -r first rest; do
    echo "$first ${rest// /-}"
done < test.txt
```

Note that this will *not* collapse whitespace, so if you have a line with multiple blanks between words, like

```
hello     there     big     world
```

you'll get this output:

```
hello there-----big-----world
```

If you'd prefer only a single hyphen, then you can read the words into a bash array:

```
while read -ra words; do
    echo "${words[0]} $(IFS=-; echo "${words[*]:1}")"
done < test.txt
```